# .htaccess redirection to subfolder _and_ https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a domain in /public_html/subfolder/, so I'm using .htaccess in public_html with this content:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subfolder/index.php [L]
```

It works fine, but I'd like to add additional redirection to https://

Tried some .htaccess modifications but with no luck: I'm getting redirection loop error ("Too many redirections") or URL with the additional part, like:

https://domains.com/**subfolder**/page.html

instead

https://domains.com/page.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule to redirect **http** to **https** and **root uris** to **subfolder** :

```
RewriteEngine on

#http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
#rewrite root requests to subfolder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /subfolder%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Replace **www.example.com** with your domain name.

Comment: Yes, I've checked this solution before: at first redirect to https:// and then  to subfolder, but it causes 'Too many redirections' error

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar configuration but I am using two entries in the .htaccess. You can take a look at my configuration at https://snetts.com

The web content is in a subfolder and I am using .htaccess to also force https://

My .htaccess is as below:

```
RewriteEngine On

#redirecting non-ssl to ssl:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L] 

#redirecting primary domain to subdirectory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^subfolder/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

You can give this a test and see if it works for you. If there are any improvements that can be made then feel free.